# Session info gets cleared when restart the app(asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session

I'm learning asp.net core(using version 2.1); I'm using a session to store some user info but everytime I stop the app and run it again session info gets cleared entirely(still have the session cookie in the browser)I have these in my startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]));
        
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSession(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "Cart";
            config.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            config.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        });
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

can someone tell me what's happening?

Comment: You can refer different session state management n Asp.Net Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: And is your session data backed by some persistent storage, like a DB or is it RAM based and only remembered while the server is running?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not storing in a DB etc. How can I do that? and is it needed when the app is deployed on a server?

Comment: No, memory based sessions will work fine as long as the server has enough memory to remember all the sessions for all the concurrent users. Memory based sessions does explain why your server doesn't remember your user sessions between each stop/start cycle though...

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi: Hello, Have you figured out a solution to this?

Comment: @user575219 Hi, well as pointed out by Caius Jard this isn't a much of a problem, because when the app is deployed on a server, it's not gonna stop(at least that much), so it won't forget the sessions.

Comment: @user575219 Also as Caius Jard said you can store your sessions data in a DB, etc..

Comment: @HosseinEbrahimi: I didn't see this message until now. I implemented IDistributeCache sqlserver to store the session key in a table. Now after looking at your comment, I feel like its an overkill.  I could have left it as a static object since it is not going to step too much in production. I might consider leaving it as static object by reverting changes. Thank you for the help.